# React Native: `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react2.PropTypes.string')`

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I've recently upgraded react-native

`"react-native": "^0.50.4",`

and react

`"react": "^16.2.0",`

I'm using mapbox additionally along with FBSDK, React-Native-Router-Flux, etc and I'm getting the following error

`undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react2.PropTypes.string')`

My `package.json` is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "clustr",
  "version": "0.9.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "remotedev": "remotedev --hostname=localhost --port=8000",
    "flow": "flow"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl": "^6.0.1",
    "fuzzysearch": "^1.0.3",
    "haversine": "^1.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.19.3",
    "moment-business": "^3.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.50.4",
    "react-native-branch": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.10.2",
    "react-native-drawer-layout": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^0.6.3",
    "react-native-geocoder": "^0.4.8",
    "react-native-hyperlink": "0.0.10",
    "react-native-i18n": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^0.5.2",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^1.3.8",
    "react-native-page-control": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-qrcode": "^0.2.6",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "0.0.22",
    "react-native-radio-buttons": "^0.14.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "3.38.0",
    "react-native-swipe-gestures": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-form": "^6.6.3",
    "redux-form-material-ui": "^4.3.1",
    "redux-saga": "^0.15.3",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.7",
    "tipsi-stripe": "^3.9.1",
    "url-parse": "^1.1.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^2.7.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.45.0",
    "remotedev-server": "0.2.2"
  },
  "assets": [
    "./assets/fonts"
  ]
}
```

With the upgrade I've swapped over to using `prop-types` as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import Text from '../generic/CText';
import {Platform, TouchableOpacity, View, Image} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


TitleBar.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string
};

export default TitleBar;
```

And so on, this is consistent across all of my components.

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Using react-codemon, run on your projects directory

jscodeshift -t react-codemod/transforms/React-PropTypes-to-prop-types.js myapp/

This will resolve updating proptypes for your source code and any node modules.

Re-installing node modules will require running the command again it seems.

Please follow instructions over at https://github.com/reactjs/react-codemod but essentially once you've installed jscodeshift, and you've downloaded the react-codemod files as above for the various commands such as transforming React.propTypes to PropTypes and so on.

myapp/ here corresponds to my entire application project directory so the entire react-native project.

Secondly, consider the project dependencies you're using. For example in my case I was using react-native-router-flux at version 0.38.0, the app would work in debug mode, but crash in release. I attempted to upgrade to the latest beta version of 4.0.0-beta.24 and the problem was resolved.

Comment: Hi @DineshSpartacus I've updated the answer, I hope it helps but basically install `jscodeshift`, download `react-codemod` transformation files over at https://github.com/reactjs/react-codemod  and specify your projects directory at the end.

Comment: thanx fro reply but I am facing this issue when I am trying to use flux..previous i have used flux in another project perfectly but now I am trying to add Router it's showing above error and without using router flux it's working fine...I don't know what is going wrong. I wasted two days on this .

Comment: @DineshSpartacus Hello, I've added some more details to the answer, in my case it seems related to that I was using `0.38.0` and the issues seems to have been resolved in the latest beta version.

To add, I don't know how much time went by in hope that the release app would just start up successfully, there was no obvious reason, no indication, until I looked in Android Device Monitor for when running the release build seeing things related to `react-native-router-flux`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I have resolved that issue....and all thanks to you......you answer should be accepted so other can follow your answer as I was hesitating to follow your answer in starting :p

Comment: Hey Michael send me your gmail id so I can share some details with you ?

Comment: Pleased to hear @DineshSpartacus and I don't blame you, I must admit it does seem iffy but thats the problem when you have conflicting libraries, for example I wanted to implement MapBox, I wasn't able to on a previous version of react, an upgrade was needed, and so I did, but then with the upgrade further issues arrose such as this one haha :)

Comment: totally agree with you @Michael as I was doing social integration I have faced lot off issues there as well....React native is simply awesome when we deals with components and other features but when we need to integrate library for access the native features of Android and IOS then it is like hell.... :)

Comment: @Micahel did you integrate social login ? I want to discuss with you can you please share your email id or skype id so we can discuss over there ?